# Titanium SDK 3.2.0 - My Android app's STOP at splash screen

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, splash-screen

[Android]

I have an Alloy Project

After my Titanium SDK's upgraded to 3.2.0,

I "Clean" my project and..

..

When I "Debug" on my Device, my App is working very well.

But when I "Run" on my Device, my App is STOP at splash screen.

Please help me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: My app has ran on Emu but when It run on device: "[ERROR] :  Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same problem and solved by deleting device sdcard/appid/deploy.json.
just like: sdcard/com.xxx.xxx/deploy.json

Hope this will help you.