# Titanium 3.4.1 Alloy - Android app's STOP at splash screen

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy, splash-screen

[Android]

I have an Alloy Project with Titanium SDK's 3.2.0,

I "Clean" my project and "Debug" on my Device, my App is working very well.

But when I Re-launch the app on my Device, it STOP at splash screen.

Refer the answer at [Titanium SDK 3.2.0 - My Android app's STOP at splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764718/titanium-sdk-3-2-0-my-android-apps-stop-at-splash-screen), I dont has **sdcard/appid/deploy.json**.

Please help me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Waiting to connect to the debugger?

Comment: i think so. Now i able to run the app without connected the device to PC. To able to run it, i clean and rebuild the app before run. I also don't know what is the issue.